# Cannot access from browser on port 3000 even though added to incoming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an Ubuntu EC2 instance. I then am running a node.js express server on port 3000. Doing a curl to `http://localhost:3000` gives me the HTML string I expect.

However when I try to access from the browser with the `Public DNS (IPv4)` which is `ec2-18-221-209-77.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`. It is not loading. The browser spins forever at `http://ec2-18-221-209-77.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000`.

I did put in my security group inbound rules, 3000 for Custom TCP and I set the source to anywhere. screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxcBQ.png

I also did netstat -tulnp and it seems :::3000 is open but only on tcp6, do I need it in TCP too? How can I do this? Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWoZe.png

Comment: Is your node.js express server listening on all interfaces? I.e `app.list(3000, '0.0.0.0')` ?

Comment: Thanks @rahoogan - no I didn't know that, this tutorial didn't say to do that though - https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-creating-and-managing-a-node-js-server-on-aws-part-1-d67367ac5171 - how come they didn't call this out? I added this in but its still not working - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/6861184ad54d860da4c1ac9cfd14d30a

Comment: You probably need to clear your cache. The URL worked for me. I get "Hello Digital Ocean!" response from `http://ec2-18-221-209-77.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000`.

Comment: Oh no way, thats real weird @rahoogan, did it work only after me adding the `0.0.0.0` for you? Did you try it before that change? Weirdest thing is for me I tried in multiple browsers same issue. I even tried in a browser i never used before.

Comment: I only just tried it now, but I would say there's some caching happening somewhere. Try restarting your machine or try from a different one.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and let you know!

Comment: Wow nuts i restarted computer and still no. Ill keep trying.

Comment: what's the output of ```netstat -pant | grep 3000```. It should be ```0.0.0.0``` if you want to access it from outside.

Comment: Oh wow I tried from a different computer on a different network (my home computer) and it worked! That is so weird why it doesnt work from my work computer and network.

Comment: @kintuparantu I will try that out today and share with you, thanks!

Comment: ```curl -v ec2-18-221-209-77.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000``` and ```curl -I ec2-18-221-209-77.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000```

Comment: @kintuparantu the `netstat` yielded `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10177/index.js` and the curls both gave status response 200 from the server. But curls from my local terminal just hang - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/613efc5612c2f6bcb320bba22eeaefa1

Comment: what about the NACLs in AWS ?

Comment: What is NACLs @kintuparantu?